# How do I change rows and columns in a dask dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dask

There are few issues I am having with Dask Dataframes.

lets say I have a dataframe with 2 columns `['a','b']`

if i want a new column `c = a + b`

in pandas i would do :

```
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

In dask I am doing the same operation as follows:

```
df = df.assign(c=(df.a + df.b).compute())
```

is it possible to write this operation in a better way, similar to what we do in pandas?

Second question is something which is troubling me more.

In pandas if i want to change the value of `'a'` for row 2 & 6 to `np.pi` , I do the following

```
df.loc[[2,6],'a']  = np.pi
```

I have not been able to figure out how to do a similar operation in Dask. My logic selects some rows and I only want to change values in those rows.

Answer (score 8):

#### Edit Add New Columns

Setitem syntax now works in dask.dataframe

```
df['z'] = df.x + df.y
```

#### Old answer: Add new columns

You're correct that the setitem syntax doesn't work in [`dask.dataframe`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html).

```
df['c'] = ... # mutation not supported
```

As you suggest  you should instead use `.assign(...)`.

```
df = df.assign(c=df.a + df.b)
```

In your example you have an unnecessary call to `.compute()`.  Generally you want to call compute only at the very end, once you have your final result.

#### Change rows

As before, `dask.dataframe` does not support changing rows in place.  Inplace operations are difficult to reason about in parallel codes.  At the moment `dask.dataframe` has no nice alternative operation in this case.  I've raised [issue #653](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/653) for conversation on this topic.

Comment: Is there an idiomatic way to handle the change rows operation using Dask? This was answered quite a while ago so maybe support has been added? Specifically for this type: `ddf['c'][f] = np.nan`

Comment: No.  Changing individual rows in lazy parallel data structures is very hard.  However if you have a well-formed index then you might consider using `where`.