# assign() to variable column name in dask DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have code that works in `pandas`, but I'm having trouble converting it to use `dask`. There is a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363114/how-do-i-change-rows-and-columns-in-a-dask-dataframe), but it does not allow me to use a variable as the name of the column I am assigning to.

Here's the working `pandas` code:

```
percent_cols = ['num_unique_words', 'num_words_over_6']

def find_fraction(row, col):
    return row[col] / row['num_words']

for c in percent_cols:
    df[c] = df.apply(find_fraction, col=c, axis = 1)
```

Here's the broken `dask` code:

```
data = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)

for c in percent_cols:
    data = data.assign(c = data[c] / data.num_words)
```

This assigns the result to a new column called `c` rather than modifying the value of `data[c]` (what I want). Creating a new column would be fine if I could have the column name be a variable. E.g., if this worked:

```
for c in percent_cols:
    name = c + "new"
    data = data.assign(name = data[c] / data.num_words)
```

For obvious reasons, python doesn't allow an expression left of an `=` and thus ignores the previous value of `name`.

How can I use a variable for the name of the column? The for loop iterates far more times than I'm willing to copy/paste.

Comment: `.apply` does work the same.  It's just that you can't mutate dask DataFrames like you can in pandas, as described in the linked question.  In other words, in your code, the `.apply` works fine; it's the `data[c] = ...` that doesn't work.