# variable column name in dask assign() or apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have code that works in `pandas`, but I'm having trouble converting it to use `dask`. There is a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363114/how-do-i-change-rows-and-columns-in-a-dask-dataframe), but it does not allow me to use a variable as the name of the column I am creating/assigning to.

Here's the working `pandas` code:

```
percent_cols = ['num_unique_words', 'num_words_over_6']

def find_fraction(row, col):
    return row[col] / row['num_words']

for c in percent_cols:
    df[c] = df.apply(find_fraction, col=c, axis=1)
```

Here's the `dask` code that doesn't do what I want:

```
data = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=8)

for c in percent_cols:
    data = data.assign(c = data[c] / data.num_words)
```

This assigns the result to a new column called `c` rather than modifying the value of `data[c]` (what I want). Creating a new column would be fine if I could have the column name be a variable. E.g., if this worked:

```
for c in percent_cols:
    name = c + "new"
    data = data.assign(name = data[c] / data.num_words)
```

For obvious reasons, python doesn't allow an expression left of an `=` and ignores the previous value of `name`.

How can I use a variable for the name of the column I am assigning to? The loop iterates far more times than I'm willing to copy/paste.

Answer (score 3):

This can be interpreted as a Python language question:

**Question**:  How do I use a variable's value as the name in a keyword argument?

**Answer**:  Use a dictionary and `**` unpacking

```
c = 'name'
f(c=5)       # 'c' is used as the keyword argument name, not what we want
f(**{c: 5})  # 'name' is used as the keyword argument name, this is great
```

#### Dask.dataframe solution

For your particular question I recommend the following:

```
d = {col: df[col] / df['num_words'] for col in percent_cols}
df = df.assign(**d)
```

#### Consider doing this with Pandas as well

The `.assign` method is available in Pandas as well and may be faster than using `.apply`.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in the `d =` line?

Comment: We make a dictionary mapping column names to new columns that we want to put into the dataframe.  This is the same as the for loop over your call to `assign`.