# How to assign a value to a column in Dask data frame

Tags: python, insert, append, dask

How to do the same as the bellow code for a dask data frame.

```
df['new_column'] = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (condition):
        df[i,'new_column'] = '1'
    else:
        df[i,'new_column'] = '0'
```

I want to add a new column to a dask dataframe and insert 0/1 to the new column.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not wish to compute as suggested by Rajnish kumar, you can also use something along the following lines:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_df = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_df)
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
dask_df["c"] = dask_df.apply(lambda x: x["a"] < 2, 
                             axis=1, 
                             meta=pd.Series(name="c", dtype=np.bool))
dask_df.compute()
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   True
1   2   3   False
```

The condition (here a check whether the entry in column `"a" < 2`) is applied on a row-by-row-basis. Note that depending on your condition and dependencies therein it might not necessarily be as straightforward, but in that case you could share additional information on what your condition entails.

Comment: Indeed I have to work with dask data frame. The condition is as follows: in random, 0.2 of the new column values should be 1 and the other values should be 0.

Comment: @Fatemeh: Assume you have 5 partitions of same size in your dask `DataFrame`, would it be fine if each partition contains a fraction of 0.2 1s or should the condition also cover the case where individual partitions contain more 1s than others? Should there be 20% of 1s by expectation or exactly 20% all the times?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if I understand your question as well. So I explained my problem more. I was trying to split the dask dataframe to train_test (in order to apply it to an auto-encoder) but the 'dask_ml.model_selection.train_test_split()` kills the kernel. So I would like to use a 0/1 column that 0 shows the train data and 1 shows test values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly to Dask Dataframe. You first need to compute it. Use this, It will work.

```
df = df.compute()
for i in range(len(df)):
if (condition):
    df[i,'new_column'] = '1'
else:
    df[i,'new_column'] = '0'
```

The reason behind this is Dask Dataframe is the representation of dataframe schema, it is divided into dask-delayed task. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I need to stick to Dask data frame because of RAM issues. Any suggestion on how to insert a value to a dask data frame?

Comment: [See this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363114/how-do-i-change-rows-and-columns-in-a-dask-dataframe). Here it is answered with reason

Answer (score 0):

I was going through these answers for a similar problem I was facing.

This worked for me.

```
def extractAndFill(df, datetimeColumnName):
  # Add 4 new columns for weekday, hour, month and year
  df['pickup_date_weekday'] = 0 
  df['pickup_date_hour'] = 0
  df['pickup_date_month'] = 0
  df['pickup_date_year'] = 0

  # Iterate through each row and update the values for weekday, hour, month and year
  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Get weekday, hour, month and year
    w, h, m, y = extractDateParts(row[datetimeColumnName])

    # Update the values
    row['pickup_date_weekday'] = w
    row['pickup_date_hour'] = h
    row['pickup_date_month'] = m
    row['pickup_date_year'] = y

  return df

df1.compute()
df1 = extractAndFill(df1, 'pickup_datetime')
```